# Import excel data given in each repeated 5 rows to one row in database. Laravel 5.8

Tags: excel, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel

I've an excel file with following data. The below is the data of 2 users. Each user have 5 rows of details. I need to import the following to 2 rows in database.

[image: excel]

The below is my table structure

[image: Database table structure]

What I need is, I need to import the excel in such a way, in the table there should be only 2 rows like below.

[image: Resut]

How can I do this in Laravel 5.8.
Here is my controller code

```
public function importMovementFile (Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
           'mcafile'  => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx,ods'
          ]);

    $path = $request->file('mcafile')->getRealPath();

    $data = \Excel::import(new UsersImport,$path);

    return back()->with('success', 'Excel Data Imported successfully.');

}
```

UserImports

```
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\OnEachRow;

  class UsersImport implements OnEachRow
   {
    public function onRow(Row $row)
    {
    $rowIndex = $row->getIndex();
    $row      = $row->toArray();

   UploadMovAnalysisDataFiles::create([
        'member_name' => $row[0][$rowIndex],
    ]);
   }
 }
```

Comment: The data in your excel can be converted to the format similar to your database table using pivot table, make it similar to the database and after that you can import suing any laravel excel package

Comment: But how can I do the same using maatwebsite 3.1 excel upload

Comment: You have to be specific in your question, asking "how to do" can only be answered in a blog, not in a simple post. Proper way would be to do it your self follow any tutorial on the net and ask a question  where you feel stuck or having any bug/error type of thing.

Comment: I've added my controller and model codes. I'm using maatwebsite 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the solution to this,
We can do this by checking the name inside a for loop. First of all, check whether the name is empty or not, if empty place the first name in name variable and loop throughout. Store each scores of the corresponding name in an object. When another name comes insert the first details and loop through the next and so on.

```
    public function insertExcel
    {
    $obj= new UploadMovAnalysisDataFiles();
    $name ='';
    for($i=1;$i<$rows->count();$i++){

        if($name==''){
            $name = $rows[$i][0];
            $id = $rows[$i][1];   
            $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($rows[$i][2])); 
            $visit_date = $date;
            //function call
            score($rows[$i][3],$rows[$i][4];


    }elseif($name==$rows[$i][0]){
            //function call
            score($rows[$i][3],$rows[$i][4];

    }else{

        UploadMovAnalysisDataFiles::create([
        'member_name' => $name,
        'mov_analysis_tag_id' => $id ,
        'visit_date' => $date,
        'fitness_score' => $obj->fscore,
        'knee_score' => $obj->kscore,
        'hip_score' => $obj->hscore,
        'core_score' => $obj->cscore,
        'shoulder_score' => $obj->sscore,


    ]);
        $name = $rows[$i][0];
        $id = $rows[$i][1];   
        $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($rows[$i][2])); 
        $visit_date = $date;
        //function call
        score($rows[$i][3],$rows[$i][4]);
    }
    }



   UploadMovAnalysisDataFiles::create([
        'member_name' => $name,
        'mov_analysis_tag_id' => $id ,
       'visit_date' => $date,
        'fitness_score' => $obj->fscore,
        'knee_score' => $obj->kscore,
        'hip_score' => $obj->hscore,
        'core_score' => $obj->cscore,
        'shoulder_score' => $obj->sscore,


    ]);

   }
```

Function to keep each score in an object.

```
     function score($rows[$i][3],$rows[$i][4){
           if($rows[$i][3]== 'VSFitness_Score'){
               $obj->fscore =  $rows[$i][4];
           }if($rows[$i][3]== 'knee_Score'){
               $obj->kscore =  $rows[$i][4];
           }if($rows[$i][3]== 'Hip_Score'){
               $obj->hscore =  $rows[$i][4];
           }if($rows[$i][3]== 'Core_Score'){
               $obj->cscore =  $rows[$i][4];
           }if($rows[$i][3]== 'Shoulder_Score'){
               $obj->sscore =  $rows[$i][4];
           }
      }
```